# Unexpected behavior when trying to change progress bar value every second

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to increment progress bar value every second, but every time I increment variable, value start incrementing faster then I defined.

Here is an example:

```kotlin
var progress by remember { mutableStateOf(0.00f) }
val animatedProgress by animateFloatAsState(
    targetValue = progress,
    animationSpec = ProgressIndicatorDefaults.ProgressAnimationSpec
)

val mainHandler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
mainHandler.post(object : Runnable {
    override fun run() {
        progress += 0.01f
        println(progress)
        mainHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000)
    }
})

LinearProgressIndicator(progress = animatedProgress)
```

I don't know what to do. I tried the same thing with normal float and it works.

```kotlin
var i = 0.00f
val mainHandler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
mainHandler.post(object : Runnable {
    override fun run() {
        i += 0.01f
        println(i)
        mainHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000)
    }
})
```

Comment: Remember that composition must not have side effects. Posting something to a handler that modifies your state is a side effect. You should read about LaunchedEffects, which are a safe way to do side effects.

Comment: Thank you! I am new to compose and I haven't heard anything about side effects before. I would probably spend next two weeks trying to solve this problem. You really helped me a lot. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you already use `jetpack-compose` so use `jetpack-compose` power with `LaunchedEffect` to get `CoroutineScope` instead of `Handler` for your delay.
Code example:

```
 var progress by remember { mutableStateOf(0.00f) }
    val animatedProgress by animateFloatAsState(
        targetValue = progress,
        animationSpec = ProgressIndicatorDefaults.ProgressAnimationSpec
    )

    LaunchedEffect(key1 = progress, block = {
        delay(1_000)
        if (progress < 1f) {
            progress += 0.1f
        }
    })

    LinearProgressIndicator(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        progress = animatedProgress
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like:

```
val state = remember { ProgressState() }

DisposableEffect(Unit) {
    state.start()
    onDispose {
        state.stop()
    }
}

CircularProgressIndicator(progress = state.progress)
```

with:

```
private class ProgressState {
    var progress by mutableStateOf(0f)

    fun start() {
        handler.postDelayed(updateProgress, 500)
    }

    fun stop() {
        handler.removeCallbacks(updateProgress)
    }

    val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
    val updateProgress: Runnable = object : Runnable {
        override fun run() {
            if (progress < 1f) {
                progress += 0.10f
            }
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]